# User-defined types of specific values in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

I have googled the heck out of this, but haven't been able to find anything relevant (surprises me, since it would seem to be an obvious thing many would want to try).

I want to do something like this:

```
data Car = "ford" | "chevy"
```

In other words, I want the values on the right hand side to be specific values, i.e. particular strings, particular numbers, etc. rather than something general.

Is this possible?  How do I do it?

Thanks.

EDIT:  I am not looking for: data Car = Ford | Chevy

Comment: Can you clarify what is wrong about `data Car = Ford | Chevy`?

Comment: I want types which correspond to a range of real-world values.  I am not going to be processing Fords or Chevys, I will be processing "fords" or "chevys".  One does not add One and Two together (try it, any compiler will blow up), One must add 1 and 2.  I will be using my program to process real world values.  Therefore I need types to map to real-world types.  I do see the utility and value of having the option to go Ford and Chevy.  It just isn't what I want in this particular case.

Comment: Please paste some code (or pseudo-code) that illustrates how you want to use `Car`.  The example you gave about adding `One` and `Two` together would be solved by simply using an existing type for numbers.  It's likely that you might want something like `type Car = String` in this particular case.

Comment: I know you are trying to help.  I thought the whole point of a type was to differentiate what is included in the set of the type from what isn't.  I don't want any old string value to pass for a car, cars are PARTICULAR strings, just like the class of integers doesn't include any number like 3.567.  Having a Car just be a general string sort of defeats the whole purpose, in my opinion.

Comment: I second Matts suggestion about adding some pseudocode. Although I can't be certain what you have in mind, I think you will find that `data Car = Ford | Chevy` will work well. Can you give an example, where your suggested solution adds some benefit and no drawbacks?

Comment: Well what if a user is supposed to enter the car make into the program in order to do whatever.  Wouldn't I want to check that the make is a valid make?

Comment: @RG Yes, that's why Matt's solution is the correct one. The compiler automatically checks the make is valid. And with `carToString` you still get the string representation you want! The best of both worlds :)

Comment: You could derive a read instance for your car type, then use reads to decide if the input car is in fact a Car. This requires normalizing the input to match the show instance, however, but that should be trivial.

Comment: Yup, that's in fact what I'm doing.  It is sort of the opposite of the "show" thing.  Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: Why on earth was this question closed as Not Constructive? Without even a comment? *"We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."* This question already *had* answers supported by facts and specific expertise at the time that it was closed! Just because it's a question that Haskell experts might think is silly, doesn't mean it's not a good question!

Comment: @Ben: Because "not constructive" is the catch-all close reason these days. Sigh. That said... wanting to do something that indicates having at least one fundamental misunderstanding of the language while specifically excluding the only sensible answer for no clear reason is what *does* mean it's not a good question. If anything it's "too localized", i.e., the question is not relevant outside confused notions specific to the OP.

Comment: @C.A.McCann Being confused about `data` declarations is quite common amongst people learning Haskell, so I think there's relevance. The exclusion of `data Car = Ford | Chevy` was also edited into the question after MattS's original answer, which basically said `data Car = Ford | Chevy` without adding any commentary explaining why that really did serve the OP's purpose after all (which was what prompted me to add my long-winded answer). Most questions asked by learners of any programming language stem from not-yet-understanding some fundamentals; I don't think that makes them poor questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not directly possible in Haskell. `data Car = "ford" | "chevy"` looks like it's attempting to create a subtype of `String`; all `Car` values would be `String`s, but not all `String`s would be `Car`s. More general usage of the syntax you're trying would create bizarre types that are undiscriminated unions of subtypes (for example `data Strange = 1 | "one" | '1'`.

Haskell's type system doesn't have sub-typing, so this is never going to work directly.

If you don't actually care that the values of the type `Car` are `String`s, then you can just use `data Car = Ford | Chevy` (as proposed by Matt S).

If you do care that the values of type `Car` are `String`s, presumably this is because you want to be able to apply functions taking `String` to `Car` values, but you don't want to be able to pass any old `String` as a `Car`.

A different way to achieve that from creating a `Car` type that **is** only the `String`s you want is to create a `Car` type plus a function that gives you the `String` corresponding to any given `Car`. For example:

```
data Car = Ford | Chevy

carStr :: Car -> String
carStr Ford = "ford"
carStr Chevy = "chevy"
```

Then you can pass around `Car` values and do `Car` operations on them, and whenever you actually need the value as a `String` (such as for printing) you just invoke `carStr` on it.

There is however the `Show` class for types that can be converted to a `String`, and you can automatically get an instance of `Show` like so:

```
data Car = Ford | Chevy
    deriving Show
```

Then the `show` function will render the `Ford` constructor as the `String` `"Ford"`, and `Chevy` as `"Chevy"`. That isn't exactly what you originally had, because the first letter is capitalised (the data constructor names have to begin with an upper case letter, and the derived `Show` instance will match the constructor names). You could manually write your own `Show` instance instead of deriving it, like so:

```
data Car = Ford | Chevy

instance Show Car where
    show Ford = "ford"
    show Chevy = "chevy"
```

But since so many `Show` instances produce exactly Haskell syntax for the values they render, I tend to think it's best not to depart from this where possible. But you can get the best of both worlds, and have an auto-derived `Show` instance so you don't have to manually set the correspondence between data constructors and the strings they produce, *plus* an different function that produces the specific strings you wanted:

```
import Data.Char

data Car = Ford | Chevy
    deriving Show

carStr :: Car -> String
carStr = map toLower . show
```

Answer (score 8):

`data Car = Ford | Chevy`

Data constructors aren't strings.  Note that the capitalization of the first letter is not optional.  In haskell, data constructors must have their first letter capitalized, and identifiers for values must have non-capital first letters.

Edited:

Here's how you can both limit values of type `Car` to `Ford` and `Chevy` and still use them as strings:

```
data Car = Ford | Chevy

carToString Ford = "Ford"
carToString Chevy = "Chevy"
```

Then, you would create a value with something like `mycar = Ford` and anytime you wanted to use the values as strings you would simply use `carToString mycar`.

Comment: "Data constructors aren't strings" - of course that is obvious, and it is also obvious that what I'm trying to do doesn't work, because the compiler doesn't allow it.  What I'm asking is how to do something like the above.  How do I achieve what I want to achieve?  Thanks.

Comment: @RG He's telling you how to achieve what you want to achieve. You may not like it, but that's not Matt's problem. (More constructively: if you want a different answer, you have to say what bad property this answer has that a good answer would not have, rather than just saying "there exists a bad property that this answer has". We don't know what you want to achieve, and we can't read your mind!)

Comment: What do you want `data Car = "ford" | "chevy"` to mean?  Do you want values of type `Car` to be `String`s that must equal either "ford" or "chevy"?  That is not possible.  However, it's virtually certain that whatever you're trying to do can easily be done within the type system.

Comment: Yes, I wanted Car to be strings that must equal "ford" or "chevy."  If you say it isn't possible, I guess I'm shocked.  It doesn't do me any good to define a Car as simply a string... what if I accidentally typed in "chevry" instead of "chevy?"  I thought this is the type of problem strong typing was supposed to solve?  Anyway, thanks for the help, I guess.

Comment: I believe that my edit explains how to gain that type safety and still use the values as strings when necessary.

Comment: Well I guess I'll accept your answer if no one comes up with something better.  It just seems that I could do away with with the whole Car type and just move to functions which check the value of strings.  But then what have I gained by moving to strong typing vs. a dynamic or untyped language?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @RG Note that Matt S's answer gives you both type-safety and the string representation you want (via `carToString`). "But what do I gain from using a type, then" you ask? Well, since you're using a proper type instead of strings, you get to do pattern matching (see `carToString`) and the compiler will warn you if you miss one constructor. To see what I mean, enable warnings in your compiler and "forget" about writing the definition for `Chevy` in `carToString`.

Comment: @MattS: If you want type safety, stop trying to use strings, and use meaningful types instead. I really cannot fathom why you want to represent data as strings in the first place--it's a terrible idea, for exactly the reasons you're complaining about!

Comment: @C.A.McCann: I think you addressed that comment to the wrong person.

Comment: @C.A. McCann, you really can't fathom why someone would want to represent data as strings?  The statement boggles my mind, but to each his own I guess.

Comment: That's because there really is a better way! He can't work out why you don't like it.

Comment: I like idealized data as much as the next guy.  But people sitting at terminals enter string data types at prompts.  Databases being processed have string data, not idealized types living in a compiler.  Don't get me wrong, things like enums or Fords or Chevys are great for some kinds of computations.  They just aren't when you have to process real data from the outside world.  I need a way to check that the data coming in matches correct types.  Thus a type has to boil down to a "ford" or "chevy," not a Ford or Chevy.

Comment: @RG Have a read through [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574268/user-defined-types-of-specific-values-in-haskell/12577401#12577401). Although I use an Abstract Data type internally, I deliberately address the issue of dealing with data coming in from the outside world using `getCar`. After you've used it to clean up data (__once__), you can replace dirty user data with clean idealized types, and your code will be much lovelier. `Ford` _does_ boil down to `"ford"`,`"Ford"`, `"FORD"` etc this way, but _safely_ - the cleanness is all in your code, not in the outside world.

Comment: @RG (The only difference in my answer to the others is really the dealing with user data aspect. All the answerers agree that an Abstract Data Type _is_ what you need.)

Comment: @RG: So I assume you don't use numeric types in your programs either? After all, "idealized types" like, say, integers aren't what the user enters at a console. Does that mean the type has to boil down to strings like "4" or "11" instead of the integers 4 or 11?

Comment: @RG The **type** `Car` should be a `Ford` or a `Chevy`. Someone entering a string at a terminal can type any string, which is why you get that input in the form of a string. At that point you need to figure out the `Car` corresponding to the string, and there may not be one; the user may have typed "banana". Making a sub-type of string that can only be "ford" or "chevy" wouldn't help you with that problem, because the input would still be in the form of a general string, and you still have to convert the general string to your more specific string.

Comment: @RG Using specific types means you **only** have to deal with that problem at the "outer" layer where you're converting user-input into your internal data formats (and where you can probably do something sensible, like ask the user for a correction). Using strings everywhere means you need to deal with the possibility that **any** function could be invoked on `"banana"` when it should only be invoked on "ford" or "chevy".

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be very important to you to have Strings, but you want to have type safety. Strings are inherently *not* type safe. The abstract data type *is* type safe, and once you get used to it, you'll find you like it.

One benefit is that you can allow the user to use any capitalisation (16 or 32 possibilities) but internally there's only one representation, so once you've read your data in once, using the data is fast and efficient. If you use string internally, you'lll be forever doing a more complicated capitalisation string check every time your program depends on what Car is being used.

If you're only using the `` `Car `` data type internally, you don't need strings at all, so the only reason to have strings is to deal with input and output. Here's a way of having the type safety *and* deal with input/ouput using strings. After compilation, the abstract data type has a very small data representation so runs faster than a string.

```
data Car = Ford | Chevy
  deriving (Read,Show,Eq)
```

so now we can read, show and check for equality. This gives you the ability to do

```
read "Ford" -- gives Ford
show Chevy  -- gives "Chevy"
Ford == Chevy -- gives False
read "GM" -- gives an exception. oops.
```

But perhaps more useful to you than read and show would be

```
getCar :: String -> Maybe Car
getCar xs = case toLower xs of
   "ford"   -> Just Ford
    "chevy" -> Just Chevy
    _       -> Nothing
```

This is great, because you can easily use it for error checking without throwing an exception and crashing your whole program, and your user can use whatever capitalisation they want. For a trivial example, you could write

```
feedback :: Maybe Car -> String
feedback Nothing = "Please enter a valid car. Why not use one of America's favourite brands? Ford or Chevy"
feedback (Just Ford) = "Thanks for choosing Ford."
feedback (Just Chevy) = "Thanks for choosing Chevy"
```

You'd also need

```
ungetCar :: Car -> String
ungetCar Ford  = "ford"     -- or you could use "Ford"
ungetCar Chevy = "chevy"    -- or you could use "Chevy"
```

Whether you use `"ford"` or `"Ford"` is up to you, but seeing as I'm not using this string internally for checking just for output, I may as well use the capitalisation I would in ordinary text, `"Ford"`, so then I could just write

```
ungetCar = show
```

Now in your code you'd be able to write

```
... if car == Ford then .... else .....
```

instead of

```
... if (map toLower carString) == "ford" then ... else
```

with the benefit of type safety being that if your function uses the `Car` data type, it can assume without problems that the user has entered a valid car, Ford or Chevy, and cannot crash or make errors due to strings that aren't "ford" or "chevy". This moves *all* your error checking code to the first time you use `getCar`. If you use strings, and you want your code to be robust, *every* function using cars should check that the car it's given is valid and throw an exception if not, and then you're wasting an awful lot or processor cycles and you're in error handling noodle soup. The `data Car = Ford | Chevy` has safety, speed and convenience.

Using the abstract data type allows you to program defensively whilst also checking exactly once for invalid data. For that alone, you should prefer it. It's also clear, clean and easy.

If you later add another car

data Car = Ford | Chevy | GM

you only have to updata a couple of bits of code (eg `getCar`).

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you are hoping to achieve. Sounds like you want a type that can be used anywhere a `String` can be, but at the same time, can only be a subset of the possible values that a String can be. But.. what does that really mean?

For example, should both of these functions be allowed?

```
reverseCar :: Car -> Car
reverseCar = reverse

idCar :: Car -> Car
idCar = map id
```

By inspection, you can see that `reverseCar` will produce an output value that is no longer really a `Car`. But `idChar` won't actually change anything at all, so the output is still really a `Car`. But building a compiler that can automatically check that is impossible.

So, it is not possible to have a type that can be used everywhere `String` can be, and at the same time prevent you apply functions that work on `String` but would result in a non-`Car` value.

Aside from the:

```
data Char = Ford | Chevy
```

Your options are use a type alias and some helper functions:

```
type Car = String

ford :: Car
ford = "ford"

chevy :: Car
chevy = "chevy"
```

This will prevent you from making typos like `frod` and will allow you to use a `Car` anywhere a `String` could be used. But that means that you can also apply functions like `reverse` which create invalid `Car` types.

You could go one-step more and use a newtype wrapper:

```
newtype Car = Car { carToString :: String }

ford :: Car
ford = Car "ford"

chevy :: Char
chevy = Car "chevy"
```

Then you could define a bunch of trusted functions that are safe to use an a `Car` and only export those functions, but not the `Car` data constructor. That would prevent people from applying functions like `reverse` directly to `Car`. Instead they would have to use `carToString` to tell the compile that they no longer want to restrict themselves to just `Car` safe functions.

This is likely not what you want either. But I think the more you try to explain what exactly it is that you want.. the more you will realize that what you want is inconsistent and/or impossible.

By impossible, I don't mean 'impossible in Haskell', but rather, 'you would need to solve the halting problem impossible'.

An example you gave is that `Integer` does not allow the literal, 3.567. That is mixing up to different issues. The `Integer` data type itself has no way of expressing 3.567. It looks something like:

```
data Integer = I Int32 | J [Digit]
```

That is.. it is either a small integer that can be represented by a machine int or it is a list of digits. So, the type itself explicitly prohibits the use a decimal point. Much like

```
data Car = Ford | Chevy
```

prevents you from expressing "apple".

There is also the issue of converting the numeric literal from the source code into a `Integer` value. When you write (3.567 :: Integer) that is essentially shorthand which gets expanded to something like:

```
(fromRational (3567 % 100)) :: Integer
```

And you get an error like:

```
No instance for (Fractional Integer)
      arising from the literal `3.567'
```

But.. that is the process of converting a literal value to a type like `Integer` or `Double`. There is no generic number type that `Integer` and `Double` are subtypes of.

We could do something similar for the `Car` by using quasi-quoter so that you could write:

```
myCar :: Car
myCar = [car| ford |]
```

And that would be accepted, but this would be rejected:

```
notMyCar :: Car
notMyCar = [car| apple |]
```

But now we have gone really off the deep-end and not gotten any closer to what you wanted.. though what you want is still pretty unclear.

Comment: "... what you want is inconsistent and/or impossible ... solve the halting problem impossible ..."
for the record, this kind of typing is exactly what TypeScript does (and it's really cool!)